# Pulling random data from table and then displaying it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to pull 1 random ID from a table and display the "text1" and the "text2" when they click a button. This is my current code, it does not have the button because I didn't find any help on google.

```
<?php select * from TEST order by rand() limit 1 ?>


<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Text1</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Text1" value="
<?php 

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "" . $row["text1"];
                                     }

?>">
```

Note that I have this code already at the top of the page in use for other things

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header('location:index.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

Inside the config.php it has all of the MySQL login/database info.

Comment: `it does not have the button because I didn't find any help on google.` I love how nobody uses their own brain anymore

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this makes no sense and it not doing anything as it is now..

```
<?php select * from TEST order by rand() limit 1 ?>
```

Take that out, im amazed you're not getting php errors when you try to run.. ?

In order to do this you want to structure your array first so you can pull out your random item from it.

```
$arrayOfResults = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Now we select a random item

```
$randomItem = $arrayOfResults[array_rand($arrayOfResults)];
```

and viola `echo $randomItem;` you should have what you're looking for.

the filler code ill leave to you!

As per your comments, your $random item will probably have keys.. so you can echo it as so : `$randomItem['name']` or `$randomItem['id']` where the KEY is your column ID in the database..

References :

[Array_Rand](http://php.net/array_rand)

[Fetch-assoc return details](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Im the biggest noob when it comes to php. I have no idea what you are saying... and Im wanting to only echo the "Text1" not the ID and other stuff in that table. It would help if you could put it in the full code format of what I need to use :P

Comment: @user3724476 i have updated the answer, just specify which key you want to echo `$randomItem['keyNameHere'];`

Comment: My code is now

`<?php select * from mc order by rand() limit 1 
 

 
 
?>


<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Text1</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Text1" value="
<?php 
 
    $arrayOfResults = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $randomItem = $arrayOfResults[array_rand($arrayOfResults)];
 
 echo $randomItem["username"]

?>">`

But still does not work.

Comment: @user3724476 .. it would be best to define all your working vars first before using them in the HTML, generating them with inline html is not going to make it any easier.. Maybe you should start learning with something a bit easier to get the basics down.. I dont know what that `select * from mc order by rand` is doing there but thats  a SQL query and you're not doing anything with it.? the `value=` cannot be the way you have it, you need to define the value previously.. BEFORE using it in the HTML..

Comment: Anyway u can add me on skype so I can show/send u the full code? Im just to much off a noob lol

Comment: @user3724476 im afraid not, im not a teacher and I have to get on with other stuff. http://www.sitepoint.com/php/ i suggest you take some time to learn the basics first. Sitepoint is a good reference to start from.